# Create Shell Link causes external exception EEFFACE in Delphi 2007

Tags: delphi, exception, external, delphi-2007

When debugging the following code causes external exception EEFFACE

, I have tried everything I can find on external exception EEFFACE and nothing has helped me avoid this issue.  Is there another way to do this that might slip by the fault in the debugger?

```
function CreateShellLink(const LinkFileName, AssocFileName, Desc, 
WorkDir,Args, IconFileName: string; const IconIdx: Integer): Boolean;
var
  SL: IShellLink;    // shell link object
  PF: IPersistFile; // persistant file interface to shell link object
begin

  Result := False;
  ActiveX.CoInitialize(nil);
  try
    if ActiveX.Succeeded(
      ActiveX.CoCreateInstance(
      ShlObj.CLSID_ShellLink,
      nil,
      ActiveX.CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
      ShlObj.IShellLink, SL)) then
    begin
      SL.SetPath(PChar(AssocFileName));
      SL.SetDescription(PChar(Desc));
      SL.SetWorkingDirectory(PChar(WorkDir));
      SL.SetArguments(PChar(Args));
      if (IconFileName <> '') and (IconIdx >= 0) then
        SL.SetIconLocation(PChar(IconFileName), IconIdx);
      PF := SL as ActiveX.IPersistFile;
     (*  this is where the external exception happens when debugging *)
     Result :=ActiveX.Succeeded(PF.Save(PWideChar(WideString(LinkFileName)), True));
    end;
  finally
    ActiveX.CoUninitialize;
  end;
end;
```

this is the madexcept stack trace when the external exception is thrown:

```
exception class    : EExternalException
exception message  : External exception EEFFACE.

main thread ($1c2c):
762b08b2 +62 KERNELBASE.dll                            RaiseException
21b34ef7 +33 win32debugide100.bpl Win32Debug  1574  +3 
TWin32LinkUnit.GetCppDebugHook
21b357a3 +eb win32debugide100.bpl Win32Debug  1847 +11 
TWin32Process.DoLinkUnitCreated
2087dffb +07 dbkdebugide100.bpl   Debug       8341  +1 
TProcess.LinkUnitCreated
2087b8ef +57 dbkdebugide100.bpl   Debug       7058  +7 
TEvaluatorCallback.ntfyLinkUnitDelta
77750bab +4b ntdll.dll                                 
KiUserCallbackDispatcher
7654f386 +16 USER32.dll                                CallWindowProcA
20885499 +39 dbkdebugide100.bpl   Debug      11455  +3 TDebugger.DBKWndProc
20040e4c +14 rtl100.bpl           Classes    11583  +8 StdWndProc
765538bb +0b USER32.dll                                DispatchMessageA
201625f0 +fc vcl100.bpl           Forms       8105 +23 
TApplication.ProcessMessage
2016262a +0a vcl100.bpl           Forms       8124  +1 
TApplication.HandleMessage
2016291f +b3 vcl100.bpl           Forms       8223 +20 TApplication.Run
76a78652 +22 KERNEL32.DLL                              BaseThreadInitThunk
```

Comment: I read the question a few times, I mean the question. I.e. this: *"Is there another way to do this that might slip by the fault in the debugger?"* I don't understand that, are you asking if there's another way to create a shell link? Are you asking if the debugger is faulty or not and how to workaround that?

Comment: Needs an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and clarification of the points @SertacAkyuz has mentioned.

Comment: I tried your code. Did not get an EEFFACE error (a C++ error coming from the IDE, indeed usually when debugging) in Delphi Rio. Can't test with Delphi 2007, though. It created the link i wanted. **So your code is fine, but something else (some C++ part of the IDE, probably debugger-related) seems to be causing this**. And obviously only in older versions of Delphi.

Comment: FWIW, the lowest version I have installed here is XE2, and even there it worked fine. No debugging problems.

Comment: Once problem the code has its the `IShellLink` and `IPersistFile` interfaces are being implicitly released after `CoUninitialize()` is called. They need to be released before the call instead. Either explicitly set them to `nil`, or else move the `Co(Un)Initialize()` calls outside of the function (which you should do anyway, as they don't belong inside the function to begin with).